# ¿como actualizar el contenido de un elemento html despues de haber realizado una consulta con ajax?

Tags: mysql, jquery, ajax, laravel-7

**Pido disculpas de antemano si en algún momento me enredo con lo que intento explicar para obtener su ayuda**

Hola, a todos estoy desarrollando un carrito de compras para un proyecto y estoy estancado con esta parte. Lo estoy desarrollando con laravel 7 en el backend y jquery en el frontend, y me gustaria ampliar mi pregunta para que se comprenda mejor mi duda.

Tengo este codigo html:

```
@foreach($ordenes as $orden)
 <div class="card-text border-bottom pb-2">
   <span class="btn btn-info btn-sm rest-units">-</span>
   //campo donde muestro las unidades del producto que se quiere comprar
   <span class="text-units" data-id="{{$orden->id}}">{{$orden->units}}</span> 
  <span class="btn btn-info btn-sm sum-units">+</span>
</div>
@endforeach
```

(para que se comprenda un poco mejor lo que hace este código lo reduje a las líneas que realizan la acción)

Y esos elementos `span` los utilizo como triggers para correr la función de jquery ( para evitar que un botón me refresque la pagina antes de que se termine de cargar el js ).

El código js con jquery es este:

```
// evento que resta unidades del producto y actualiza las unidades de la base de datos 
$('.rest-units').unbind().click(function(){
    var units = $(this).siblings('.text-units').text();

    if(units <= 1) {

        units = 1;

    } else {
        units--;

        var id = $(this).siblings('.text-units').data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  url+'carrito/up/'+id+'/'+units,
            success: function(response){
                //ejemplo de response
                // precio =  response.precio;
            }
        });

        $(this).siblings('.text-units').text(units);
    }

});

// evento que suma unidades del producto y actualiza las unidades de la base de datos 
$('.sum-units').unbind().click(function(){

    var units = $(this).siblings('.text-units').text();

    units++;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  url+'carrito/up/'+id+'/'+units,
        success: function(response){
            // precio =  response.precio;
        }
    });

    $(this).siblings('.text-units').text(units);
});
```

El código php con laravel 7 es este:

```
public function updateUnits($id,$units)
{
    if(isset($id) && is_numeric($id)){
        $orden = Orden::find($id);

        //aclarar que en la tabla ordenes guardo el carrito de compras y los pedidos confirmados se guardarian
        // en una tabla pedidos

        $producto = Producto::find($orden->producto_id);

        $nuevo_precio_orden = ($units * $producto->precio);

        $orden->units = $units;
        $orden->precio_orden = $nuevo_precio_orden;
        $orden->update();
    }
}
```

Todo ese codigo realiza lo que quiero y actualiza las unidades de la base de datos y el precio de esa orden.

Aquí mi problema, al hacer click rápidamente ( n cantidad de veces ), sobre los "botones" que suman y restan las unidades lo que pasa es que el campo de unidades me muestra que si se ha restado o sumado esas 'n' unidades pero al revisar la base de datos me muestra que las unidades no son las mismas.

**en resumen y para terminar con un ejemplo.**

Tengo 30 unidades y presiono 5 veces sobre el botón para sumar. El campo de unidades me indica que si he sumado 5 unidades, pero al momento de revisar la base de datos puede ser que solo se haya aumentado 3 o 4 pero nunca el numero de veces que he dado click, ( esto solo sucede si yo hago click como loco en cualquiera de los 2 "botones" siempre realizando su respectiva operación).

**Lo que quiero**

Ahora yo quiero saber si hay algún método para actualizar lo que se muestra en la página, pero que sea lo mismo que tengo en la base de datos (no obligatoriamente lo mismo pero si que respete la cantidad) y también si habría algún proceso mejor para realizar la actualización de esos datos y mostrarlos en la vista.

**Muchas gracias y espero su ayuda realmente**

Comment: La respuesta de Ajax llegaría aquí: `success: function(response){ //leer response y actualizar los elementos aquí}`, dentro de ese mismo bloque, podrás leer `response` y actualizar los elementos del DOM. O bien puedes desde ahí llamar a otra función y pasarle `response`.

Comment: En la función de Laravel no se ve lo que devuelve, o sea no tiene un `return`. No lo pusiste en la pregunta o realmente no tiene `return`?

Comment: Para evitar las pulsaciones continuas en el boton, puedes poner una ventana de carga que evite que el usuario realize otra vez la accion, asi le das al servidor oportunidad de terminar el proceso, ademas asi le puedes decir al usuario que se ha terminado el proceso.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si tiene return pero no lo puse, porque retorna un booleano que me indica que si se ha realizado el proceso de actualización de datos, por que la suma de las unidades las actualizo con js, pero tenia esa espinita de retornar el nuevo numero de unidades y trabajar con ese dato probare con ese método para ver que tal me va y si obtengo lo que necesito. gracias por tu respuesta y me disculpo por la tardanza pero se me dificulta un poco por el trabajo.

Comment: Bueno, creo que lo más seguro es que del controlador devuelvas la cantidad que figura en la base de datos, y con ese valor actualices el DOm, como te dicen en el primer comentario

Comment: @tecnobyte la verdad es que necesito que sea una pulsación continua ( según yo para no entorpecer la experiencia de usuario) pero como digo desconozco un método optimizado para sumar las unidades, aun que probare haciendo el retorno de ese dato para capturarlo en el response y utilizarlo para mostrarlo

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias y si la verdad lo probare,

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias y colocare cualquir resultado